# DiffCallBack Isn't Getting Called?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

So , i have a ListAdapter and i am using adapter.submitList() to pass new list inside my adapter every time , but strangely it only submits the list for the first time , and the next time it just doesn't display the item inside the adapter
Here is how i am submitting my list

```
 private fun insertListToRv() {
        val mName = editText_checkbox.text.toString()
        val isChecked = false

        if (mName == "") {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please fill out all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        } else {

            val newListData = TaskList(
                mName,
                isChecked,
                0,
                mNoteId
            )
            itemList.add(newListData)
            adapter.submitList(itemList)
            Log.d("TAG2","Current List: ${adapter.currentList}")
            counter++
            editText_checkbox.setText("")
        }


    }
```

Here , itemList is a global variable ,initialized to ArrayList()

```
var itemList: MutableList<TaskList> = ArrayList()
```

I even placed some log statements inside my DiffCallBack , and it is just called once in this scenario and after that it doesn't get called at all.
Here is my DiffCallBack Class

```
class DiffCallBack(
) : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TaskList>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: TaskList, newItem: TaskList): Boolean {
        Log.d("TAG3","Inside")
        return oldItem.Taskid == newItem.Taskid

    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: TaskList, newItem: TaskList): Boolean {
        Log.d("TAG3","Inside")
        return oldItem == newItem

    }


}
```

I also debugged my code , and noticed that my adapter.currentList is getting updated .
What could be wrong with this implementation ?

Comment: Can you share the code with which you are testing ?

Comment: Just curious did you try my answer?

Comment: Yeah , it worked but had to resolve other issues for that to work properly

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem could re-using the same list

```
val newListData = TaskList(
                mName,
                isChecked,
                0,
                mNoteId
            )
       val adapterList = itemList + newListData
       adapter.submitList(adapterList)
```

Comment: I tried this , but this just keep on changing the same item on the list , for eg - if i input abc as the first list item and after that hello , it just replaces it abc by hello

Comment: `TaskList(mName, isChecked, 0,  mNoteId)` the `mNoteId`  and the `0` (zero)  are always the same. If any of those is the `Taskid` then that is your problem, because `return oldItem.Taskid == newItem.Taskid`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
    if (mName == "") {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please fill out all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    } else {

        val newListData = TaskList(
            mName,
            isChecked,
            0,
            mNoteId
        )
        itemList.add(newListData)
        adapter.submitList(itemList)

        //I have added this line code
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        Log.d("TAG2","Current List: ${adapter.currentList}")
        counter++
        editText_checkbox.setText("")
    }
```

I have read somewhere in stack overflow  I can not remember where. That in order to use  DiffCallBack the way you are doing it, you have to implement ROOM also! So be aware with this!! Otherwise you have to create a custom made DiffCallBack. So do not loose your time :) I have lost it searching for hours in my own project. You can use my answer above. If you want animation you have to specify the range of items inserted, removed etc...